# 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

**MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE gallery_id = '25'' at line 1)
Session halted.**

*Database error:*

```
UPDATE gallery_master SET gallery_title = 'Presss', gallerycat_id = '6', gallery_code = 'Presss', gallery_images = '201411121152551461105875_pressgfx1.jpg' , gallery_status = '1' , gallery_description = '' , gallery_featured = '1' , WHERE gallery_id = '25'
```

Comment: look what comes right before the snippet that says it is in error.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE gallery_master
SET gallery_title = 'Presss',
  gallerycat_id = '6',
  gallery_code = 'Presss',
  gallery_images = '201411121152551461105875_pressgfx1.jpg' ,
  gallery_status = '1' ,
  gallery_description = '' ,
  gallery_featured = '1' ,
                         ^============= here
WHERE gallery_id = '25'
```

Comment: Thnx For Reply..Its Working Fine

Answer (score 0):

remove the last comma before where clause:

```
UPDATE gallery_master SET gallery_title = 'Presss', gallerycat_id = '6', gallery_code = 'Presss', gallery_images = '201411121152551461105875_pressgfx1.jpg' , gallery_status = '1' , gallery_description = '' , gallery_featured = '1' WHERE gallery_id = '25'
```